# list comprehension with concurrent loops python

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

Simple question as i just want to write more pythonic code. I want to convert the following into a list comprehension

```
index_row = 0
for row in stake_year.iterrows():
    self.assertTrue(row[0] == counts[index_row][0])
    self.assertTrue(row[1][0] == counts[index_row][1])
    index_row += 1
```

What i don't understand is how to walk through the counts list. I don't want a nested for like:

```
[self.assertTrue(x[0] == counts[y][0] for x in stake_year for y in counts]
```

The code i have now is working but I'd like to understand python better and use the language as it should be used.

Comment: Looks to me like you want to use `enumerate()`

Comment: List comprehensions are for creating lists, not for executing loops.

Comment: Enumerate was what i want. I shouldn't have called this a list comprehension, but that's all part of the learning. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Don't forget to accept @minitoto's answer, then. :)

Comment: I assume `.assertTrue` returns `None`, so the list comp you don't want would create a list full of `None`s that you'd immediately throw away. Doing that is extremely _un_-Pythonic, and has no place in normal code... but people sometimes do that sort of thing in code golf and other weird coding games. :)

Comment: It wouldn't let me accept, i had a timer that had to expire. Everyone jumped on the answer so quickly i had to wait on the accept :) It's now accepted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The more pythonic way to use in your case is to use [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index_row, row in enumerate(stake_year.iterrows()):
    self.assertTrue(row[0] == counts[index_row][0])
    self.assertTrue(row[1][0] == counts[index_row][1])
```

Comment: This is perfect and enumerate now makes sense. Thanks @minitoto.

Answer (score 5):

Don't.

List comprehensions are not by definition more pythonic than simple loops - only if these loops are designed to build new lists (or dicts, sets etc.), and if the listcomp is easier to read than the loop.

This is not the case in your example (you're not building anything), and you shouldn't use a listcomp only for its side effects, that would be patently unpythonic.

So it's good to convert

```
result = []
for line in lines:
    result.append(line.upper())
```

into

```
result = [line.upper() for line in lines]
```

but not your example.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Tim, i'm an old dinosaur who's having fun learning python and the journey has been really fun. I keep trying to write assembler and that's not always the best way in python :)